# Use external name server for one specific cname?

Tags: linux, cname-record, bind

Right now when I `ping ex1.example.com` the IP address is looked up in my local name server.

But what I would like is that this specific cname `ex1.example.com` is always lookuped in

```
bb1dns1.na.epidm.net
bb1dns2.eu.epidm.net
bb1dns1.eu.epidm.net
```

So the question is, how is that done in bind9 on a CentOS 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a zone of type `forward` to your named.conf:

```
zone "ex1.example.com" in {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders { 10.0.0.1; 10.0.0.2 }; # adresses of the relevant servers
};
```